# How to deploy .NET Core applications

Tags: asp.net, dnx, .net-core

I'm just new with the asp.net core multi-platform thing and I was just wandering how do you deploy an application? I went to the .net core tutorial documentation but it is not written yet -

[Deploying applications manually](https://dotnet.readthedocs.org/en/latest/deployment/deployment-manual.html)

Any idea on how this can be done? Thanks.

Comment: You can do `dnu publish --no-source --runtime {runtime} -o {path}` and xcopy the folder to the target machine.

Comment: Thanks @Pawel that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue. I develop with VS2015 (Community) on Windows and wanted to tun on Linux (ASP.NET Core MVC 6 App). I use a git repository (git integrates very nicely with VS now) and on the linux server you

```
git clone https://my.git.server/myrepo.git
```

cd into the src-dir and run

```
dnu restore
```

followed by

```
dnx web
```

(if it's a web-app ;-) )

Comment: do you know how to host it on linux? ... like as we do on IIS, I need to access it using url plz help.